# Hardware GPIO watchdog in linux kernel... Autorun

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, watchdog

Just faced with interesting case of using hardware GPIO watchdog. I generate **5Hz** signal(meander) for an external system control by using gpio watchdog. To keep it running I write some data to the /dev/watchdog1 file **every 30 seconds**. Our configuration is **60 secs** for watchdog after which the  signal will be stopped. So, everything is fine, but the system is slow and user application is ready only after ~40 secs after startup. However the watchdog driver is ready already after 5 secs. For whole system this signal has to appear after startup as soon as possible.

So, I'd like that the watchdog driver runs gpio signal as soon as probe func invoked and then we have ~60 secs to take control from user application(start writing smth to the /dev/watchdog1).

**The question is**: Is it good idea to change watchdog driver to run it directly from probe func? Or maybe there is any trick to run gpio watchdog at least once, directly from driver? Or maybe there is another solution for this problem...

P.S. I use CONFIG_GPIO_WATCHDOG

Answer (score 0):

I've solved a similar problem in the past by servicing the watchdog in the boot loader.

We were using U-Boot, which has watchdog hooks in its source (specifically its kernel uImage decompression source). This meant that we could hook in some additional code to service the watchdog while the kernel image was decompressing, when neither kernel nor drivers had been loaded.

Its a bit of a different approach than what your question is asking. Instead of trying to service the watchdog as early as possible with the kernel drivers, we opted for servicing the watchdog as late as was possible with the boot loader. This bridged the time gap enough for the watchdog drivers to load and take over and keep things going.